# Facebook (Login 4.27) not returning to Swift App

Tags: swift

What happens: after logging in through the Facebook SDK the user is not returned to my app, and Facebook closes.

Lots of questions on stackoverflow like this, but I'm confused between the difference between FBSDKApplicationDelegate and SDKApplicationDelegate.

I am using

```
    - FacebookCore (~> 0.3)
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.27)
    - FBSDKShareKit (~> 4.27)
```

and add my login button as

```
let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
loginButton.loginBehavior = .native
```

but it will not return to the app after logging in.

I've tried loads of combinations in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions including

```
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

and then in openurl

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

I have added AppId, displayname, URLScheem to my plist, as well as LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Some guides say to use SDKApplicationDelegate which I *think* is the old SDK but I'm not sure. I've tried loads of combination and just can't return tot he app. Using .web as a popup is not acceptable for my user.

Comment: Also tried the button as an FBSDKLoginButton() because wondered if that was the problem. It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Incidentally I've been going through https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts but, obviously it's not swift (why would it be?) but even converting it I'm not getting the intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dependency issue. Had to update the relevant pods (i.e pod update  FBSDKLoginKit and other relevant pods) even though the version being used was not greatly out of date.